# Cocos2d animation with mask

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite, mask, sprite-sheet

I've got an animation of a man walking. The background image contains some trees. I've a mask with those trees and I want to apply it over the man, so it'll look like that the man walks behind the trees.

This is my code:

```
CCRenderTexture * rt = [CCRenderTexture 
                        renderTextureWithWidth:maskSprite.contentSizeInPixels.width 
                        height:maskSprite.contentSizeInPixels.height];
rt.position = ccp(maskSprite.contentSize.width/2, maskSprite.contentSize.height/2);
[rt.sprite setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc) { GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ZERO }];
[rt beginWithClear:0.0f g:0.0f b:0.0f a:1.0f];
[walkingManSprite visit];
[rt end];
[maskSprite setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc) { GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA }];
[rt beginWithClear:0.0f g:0.0f b:0.0f a:1.0f];
[maskSprite visit];    
[rt end];

CCSprite *retval = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rt.sprite.texture];
retval.flipY = YES;
return retval;
```

The result is that the man walks behinds the trees, but my mask is being shown as a black shadow over the background. How can I not show the mask but apply it over the animation?

Comment: Could you try removing the second 'behinWithClear' on the rt?